# Can I instantiate a class from a Runtime Shared Library through an interface?

Tags: actionscript

In my Runtime Shred Library SWF I have a class named BackButton that extends MovieClip and interfaces IGameButton:

```
package com.game.button
{
    import com.interfaces.IGameButton;

    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class BackButton extends MovieClip implements IGameButton
    {
        public var labelTxt:TextField;

        public function BackButton()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function get label():String
        {
            return labelTxt.text;
        }

        public function set label(value:String):void
        {
            labelTxt.text = value;
        }

    }
}
```

When I load the RSL into my main SWF by doing the following:

```
var backButtonClassName:String = "com.game.button.BackButton";
var BackButtonClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(backButtonClassName) as Class;
var backButton:IGameButton = new BackButtonClass();
```

I get the following error at runtime:

> Type Coercion failed: cannot convert com.game.button::BackButton@bb12af1 to com.interfaces.IGameButton.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you do var backButton:IGameButton = new BackButtonClass() as IGameButton;?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getDefinition` call needs to reference the [ApplicationDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#includeExamplesSummary) which must be set in your loader context:

```
public function loadHandler(e:Event) : void {
   var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
   var BackButtonClass : Class = loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition( "com.game.button.BackButton" );
}

var loader : Loader = new Loader();
var context : LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
loader.load( new URLRequest("backbutton.swf"), context );
```